# Return PHP Form data as hyperlinks

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to return my output data from my php form as hyperlinks to open

my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$name = $_POST['name'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$calls = $_POST['calls'];
$task1 = $_POST['task1'];
$task2 = $_POST['task2'];
$task3 = $_POST['task3'];
$task4 = $_POST['task4'];
$task5 = $_POST['task5'];


if ($_POST['clear'])
{
    $name="";
    $time="";
    $calls="";
    $task1="";
    $task2="";
    $task3="";
    $task4="";
    $task5="";
    $message1="";
    $message2="";
    $message3="";
    $message4="";
}
if ($_POST['send']) 
{
    $message1 = "Hello ,<br><br>Here's my $time update.";
    $message2 = "<br>"."Task Numbers :"."<br><br>".$task1 ."<br>".$task2 ."<br>" .$task3 ."<br>" .$task4 ."<br>".$task5."<br>";
    $message3 = "Total calls for the hour : <strong>$calls</strong>";
    $message4 = "<br>". "<br>". "Kind Regards"."<br>". "Employee";

}
?>
<html>
<style>
body {
font-family:arial;
font-size:12;
}
</style>
<title>Productivity Generator</title>
<form action = "" method = "POST">
<body>

<table border = 3>
<tr>
<td> Time: </td>
<td> <input list="times" name ="time" value = "<?php echo $time;?>" size="20">
        <datalist id="times">
            <option value="5AM">
            <option value="6AM">
            <option value="7AM">
            <option value="8AM">
            <option value="9AM">
            <option value="10AM">
            <option value="11AM">
            <option value="12PM">
            <option value="1PM">
            <option value="1:30PM">
            <option value="2PM">
            <option value="2:30PM">
        </datalist>
</tr>
<td> Calls: </td>
<td> <input type ="number" name ="calls" autocomplete="off" value = "<?php echo $calls;?>" size="20">
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Task1: </td>
<td> <input type = text name ="task1" autocomplete="off" value = "<?php echo $task1;?>" size="20" >
</tr>
<td> Task2: </td>
<td> <input type = text name ="task2" autocomplete="off" value = "<?php echo $task2;?>" size="20" >
</tr>
<td> Task3: </td>
<td> <input type = text name ="task3" autocomplete="off" value = "<?php echo $task3;?>" size="20" >
</tr>
<td> Task4: </td>
<td> <input type = text name ="task4" autocomplete="off" value = "<?php echo $task4;?>" size="20" >
</tr>
<td> Task5: </td>
<td> <input type = text name ="task5" value = "<?php echo $task5;?>" size="20" >
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan = 3>
<input type = "submit" name="send" value = "Ok" title="Click here to display values.">
<input type = "submit" name="clear" value = "Clear" title="Click here to clear text boxes.">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<font face='arial' size='2'>";
echo $message1;
echo "<br>";
echo $message2;
echo "<br>";
echo $message3;
echo "<br>";
echo $message4;
echo "</font>";
?>   
</body>
</html>
```

each task number entered by the user will output as a hyperlink and once you click the hyperlink it will open up a new tab eg : https://google.com/%user input%

Any help is much appreciated, i cant figure out how to achieve this in php , please be nice , im new to php haha

Comment: Do you know about an Anchor tag? [<a href=""...></a>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use anchor tags in order to output them as hyperlinks. Also you have to use [target Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) to open up that link in a new tab.

Hope this helps ya!

```
$link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];   //Base Uri

$message2 = "<br>"."Task Numbers :"."<br><br>"."<a target=_blank href=".$link.'/'.$task1.">Task1</a>"."<br>"."<a target=_blank href=".$link.'/'.$task2.">Task2</a>"."<br>"."<a target=_blank href=".$link.'/'.$task3.">Task3</a>"."<br>" ."<a target=_blank href=".$link.'/'.$task4.">Task4</a>"."<br>"."<a target=_blank href=".$link.'/'.$task5.">Task5</a>"."<br>";
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! it worked perfectly like i wanted to with some modifications